# Had to shim my double top plate -- how should I secure the trusses?

Tags: construction, truss, shimming

I am building a new detached garage, and one corner of the footing was about 1.5" low. To address this, I installed shims between the two top plates, as shown below. The size of the shim increases from left to right to make up the space. This way, the final height is level all the way around the building.

[image]

Now I need to secure the trusses to the top plate. For all the other trusses, I was able to use [uplift screws](https://www.fastenmaster.com/products/timberlok-heavy-duty-wood-screw.html) from inside.

For the four trusses shown, I installed the screws from above -- otherwise they would not have been long enough to grab the truss. The [manufacturer's documentation (pdf)](https://www.fastenmaster.com/document-search-results.html?lists=10010&body=timberlok) indicates this is allowable:

[image]

**Is this sufficient? Do I also need to connect down to the plate below? How?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I went with, one of two suggest by the inspector:

[image]

The double top plate acts as a diaphragm to distribute load, so it needs to be solid. I used strips of plywood of increasing thickness to shim up and fill the gap.

[As Jack suggested](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/190466/86548), I also screwed up into the trusses from the bottom, and used hurricane ties on the truss I couldn't get to from the bottom.

The inspector's other suggestion was to add a stud below each truss.

Answer (score 2):

Does the sheathing connect to the top plate securely? If not, because of the shims, you will need to run screws from below through the lower top plate. You could use long hurricane clips instead.

[image]

Photo courtesy HD Supply

I have seen long screws run through both plates from below, just like you have from the top, just run them in.

Comment: I would install (size appropriate to shim or lack of it) hurricane clips on all the trusses regardless - they are incredibly inexpensive for the job they do, and they do it well. Nothing like that feeling of "hey, but I saved $30 on hardware" as the wind howls.